# comparison of list using cmp or ==

Tags: python

I have two `list` which each contain read from a file.

Should I use `cmp(list1,list2)` or `(list1 == list2)`?

```
#! /usr/bin/env py

data = None
with open("sample",'r+') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
data[-1] = "abhishe"
data_1 = None
with open("cp.log",'r+') as f:
    data_1 = f.readlines()
data_1[-1] = "Goswami"

print "\n\n\n"
print data == data_1
print cmp(data,data_1)
```

Comment: `cmp()` has been removed in py3.x. And why are you initialising variables in python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will very rarely need to use `cmp`. `cmp` has the same effect as testing `<`, `==` and `>`, but it is less readable.

In your case, use `==` as it will perform deep list equality testing.

Answer (score 5):

If you are only interested in their **equality**, then I would say use the equality operator `==`.

The `cmp()` function gives slightly different info, [as the documentation describes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp):

> **`cmp()`** - Compare the two objects x and y and return an integer according to the outcome. The return value is:
>
> - negative if x < y
> - zero if x == y
> - strictly positive if x > y.

In your case, the "expected" result would be zero, a falsy value, which is not to intuitive if you are actually testing for equality.